# return the value with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I thought using bracket or dot notation with people.pets or people[pets] would return the results of the pets but not having luck.

> This function will be called with an array of objects. Each object
> represents an owner and will have a pets property, which will be an
> array of pet names. The function should return an array of all the
> pets' names.
>
> If passed an empty array the function should return an empty array.
>
> A typical array of owners is shown below:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Malcolm',
    pets: ['Bear', 'Minu'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Caroline',
    pets: ['Basil', 'Hamish'],
  },
];
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Looks like a homework question.

Comment: Related: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/943435)

Comment: People is probably the array.  The pets property is only present on elements of the array not the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a perfect example for the use of the Array.reduce().
It would however keep duplicates names. Let's say if two owners had the same pet name, it would appear twice, so it depends on what you want.

```js
const owners = [
  { name: "Malcolm", pets: ["Bear", "Minu"] },
  { name: "Caroline", pets: ["Basil", "Hamish"] },
];

const pets = owners.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item.pets), []);
```

Comment: in modern javascript there's `flatMap` for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I had never heard of flatMap. I just checked it out it's interesting. but in that particular case I don't know that it would be better since you would first have to get rid of the names.

Comment: sure, that's why you have to do `pets = owners.flatMap(o => o.pets)`